# Netbeans 8.1 No New Web Service Client Wizard

Tags: netbeans, wsdl

I am using Netbeans 8.1 with the Java SE runtime on Windows 10. I'm trying to write a web service client. According to this [official tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html#Exercise_3_1).

New > Web Service Client will open the New Web Service Client Wizard. For some reason there is no Web Service Client under New. Following the path New > Other opens the New File wizard but once again no Web Service Client option is to be found. Any insights to resolve this problem will be most appreciated.

Failing that the steps to manually import a WSDL into a javafx project will be satisfactory.

thank you
A.G.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the tutorial using netbeans 8.1 too, and upon creating the web service client I got the same issue. Initially the web service client option is not displayed on the wizard under the web service option. But after searching for "web service client" using the search filter in the wizard it is added.